# What's the easiest way to create a staged test environment for SQL Server Reporting Services and Web Viewer?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

For our web app, We run a stage testing environment which is a mirror of our production environment.

It's straightforward to set up a test mirror of the reporting database. However I haven't figured out a good way to mirror the dozens of reports we have on production, and point them to the test database.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your report's share a few data sources:

In your test report server, start the report manager and go to the data sources.

Click each datasource and change the connection string to point to the test server.

Comment: yes agreed. use shared datasources not embedded in the reports themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I used RSScripter http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62 a fair while back, which can copy reports from one server to another. Is a manual process however.